# How to Delete a MacOS Notification Center Widget?

Tags: macos, widgets

How to Delete a MacOS Notification Center Widget? Not how to disable it or simply turn it off, but how to completely remove it, like uninstalling it or simply finding the executable and deleting it?

Comment: Can you specify what widget you want to get rid of?

Comment: A 3rd party widget, not an Apple supplied one.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably unsafe to delete executables without knowing if the main app executable depends on them.

Widgets are `.wdgt` files. To completely remove the widgets you must delete them from your machine or move them to a different folder. There are 2 Library folders on your computer. Each Library folder has a `Widgets` folder. You may remove the widget from the widgets folder to get rid of it. One Library folder is in your home directory. `/Users/username/Library`, and the top level folder is `/Library`. You cannot edit the latter on macOS Catalina.

It may also be possible that apps bundle the widget in the `.app` bundle. So right click on the `myapp.app` file & "show package contents". Some folders in, `Resources` folder may contain a `wdgt` file.

You can also use app like [EasyFind](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) to search the whole Mac for the extension.

If you need the app, but not its widget:

Open the notification panel and click on Today at the top of the pane. After that look to the bottom of the Today view and you should see an Edit button. Click this button. Now the active widgets will appear on the left. There will be a red circle at the top of each widget. Click this to remove the widget. See the images below.

[image]

After clicking Edit we see:

[image]

Comment: Please read my question again. That only disables it or turns it off, it does not remove it from the computer.

Comment: I updated my answer. I added the part about how to delete a widget.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There are no folders named Widgets in either of the Library folders.

Comment: Are you running Mojave or Catalina?  I'm running High Sierra, maybe things got changed in the 2 new systems.

Comment: I'm running Catalina.

Comment: Mojave has `/Library/Widgets` folder and it contains calculator ,weather etc. @NickLilavois